# Access token retrieved:null. com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-authentication, clientid

My app allows users to login with Google Plus, and gets their name, and email address. I am tried to access the token.

Code to access the token:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);

        final Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task2 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            public static final int REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH = 100;

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String mScope="audience:server:client_id:899555500747-38rpnq51of946grhdvofck7r8u5p09cd.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
// Get the token for the current user
                String token = null;
                try {
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient), mScope);
                    Log.i("G token", token);
                } catch (IOException transientEx) {
                    // Network or server error, try later
                    Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                    // Recover (with e.getIntent())
                    Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    Intent recover = e.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH );
                } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
                    // The call is not ever expected to succeed
                    // assuming you have already verified that
                    // Google Play services is installed.
                    Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
                }
                return token;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
            }

        };
        task2.execute();
```

Error:

```
01-27 23:42:14.877  30994-31262/com.unicloud.mittal E/loginWithGooglePlus﹕ com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
01-27 23:42:14.877  30994-30994/com.unicloud.mittal I/loginWithGooglePlus﹕ Access token retrieved:null
```

I have tried various solutions which I could find on stackoverflow. At the moment, I am using Client ID from "Service Account" from [dev console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0), I have also tried using it for "Client ID for Android Application", it still showed the same error.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this question by replacing this line

```
String mScope="audience:server:client_id:899555500747-38rpnq51of946grhdvofck7r8u5p09cd.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
```

with this

```
String mScope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login";
```

I got the access token, and I was wondering if I am doing right. So I verified if the token was correct.
I tried to go to this address, I replaced `accessToken` with the token I retrieved.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=accessToken
```

It showed me this kind of output.

```
{
  "issued_to": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "audience": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
     "user_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://gdata.youtube.com",
     "expires_in": 3019,
     "access_type": "online"
    }
```

In the `issued_to` it showed me my Client ID for Android Application that means this token is issued to my client id. So I assume I am on the right track.